# Editing class in library1 used in another library2 cause access violation exception

Tags: c++, exception, dll, dllexport

I have a dll library 1 which has many classes these classes are used in dll library 2, I have no access to the library 2 code , i can't recompile it , i want to add some features to the classes in library 1 without affecting the work of library 2, i faced problems

what have i done?? (1) i added another constructor to the class in library 1 and library 2 keep working fine , (2) i added a public bool variable to the class in library 1, the library 2 throws an exception -access violation reading- !! i didn't remove any thing i just added new variable that caused the other library to stop working and throw access violation reading Exception.

Is this normal or what the is the solution for this

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by putting the new variable at the end of class declaration

```
class A // before editing
{
public:
    int a;
    bool b;
};

//i was doing thia
class A // when problem was caused
{
public:
    bool q;//my new item
    int a;
    bool b;
};

//what solved the problem

class A // after the problem  was solved
{
public:
    int a;
    bool b;
    bool q;//my new item
};
```

but i have no real explanation for that.

Comment: This isn't really a solution. You have to recompile `library2`, there's no way around it. For the future, you could consider minimizing compilation dependencies by using the *pimpl idiom*.

Comment: I know it's not a solution but what can i do if i have about 90 projects many of them are depending on that library, my task it to do this modification and keep other libraries working??. by the way it's my first time to read about http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom. but it's not a solution in this case. but do you have a any explanation of why it worked after putting the variable at the end of the members declaration? i really like to know!!

Comment: Your client libraries think that `class A` has a certain size, and that it contains only a `int` followed by a `bool`. Your second version kind of matches that, except that the clients know nothing about the second `bool`. The class' size is still different and at some point the code will run into undefined behaviour. So it looks like a solution, but it isn't.